# Distribution Function X+Y of Dependent Log-Normal Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

if $X$ and $Y$ are Log-Normal Distributions with $\mu_X,\sigma_X$, and $\mu_Y,\sigma_Y$, what is the distribution of $X+Y$? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Distributiions of $X+Y$ is not determined by distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they are independent you can use the convolution formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) and thus have that
\begin{align*}
f_{Z}(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_{Y}^{2}}} \frac{1}{(z-x)} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{Y}^2} ( ln(z-x) - \mu_{Y})^2 } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_{X}^{2}}} \frac{1}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma_{X}^2} ( ln(x) - \mu_{X})^2 } dx
\end{align*}
but I doubt it has a closed form

Comment: You should not answer very low quality questions.